# WPF application is not closing correctly

Tags: wpf, shutdown, application-shutdown

I am calling `Application.Current.Shutdown()` from a class that is bound to xaml windows with `ObjectDataProvider`, but the application is not closing. Can anyone help me to understand why? My application is not closing completely after my main window is closed, it doesn't disappear from task manager's process list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you created any threads to do background processing? If you have, make sure to set the `.IsBackground` property on them, or they can keep the app running

Comment: No, i doesn't create threads directly, may be WPF do bindings or objectdataprovider resources in other thread?

Answer (score 26):

Try `Environment.Exit(0)` instead

Comment: calling `Shutdown()` from within `override OnStartup()` was NOT working.  `Environment.Exit(0)` works

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to add this:

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple windows or dialogs in your application, you may need to close each one explicitly.

Close dialogs with:

> _myDialog.Close();

Close all windows:

```
foreach(var window in Application.Current.Windows.ToList())
{
    window.Close();
}
```

Comment: I try this, it doesn't help, i realize where is the problem, the problem is that when i call shutdown() or close() the objectdataprovider execution is not terminated, I think it will be better to add a new question, what I will do now :)

Comment: surely you could replace the for(i...) with a foreach? manually iterating over loops is so last century :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem where the application would not shut down even when main window was closed. It turned out I had done Hide() on the splash screen instead of Close() so it was still lurking in the background keeping the application alive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the application process doesn't stop although the application closed.

In my case I opened a window from a BackgroundWorker (code below)

```
BackgroundWorker BG = new BackgroundWorker();
BG.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BG_DoWork);
StockMinWindow MinWindow = new StockMinWindow(null); -------- this is the problem 
BG.RunWorkerAsync();
```

instanciate the window before running the BackgroundWorker seem not being the problem but by erasing the line the application closed correctly

I open my window from the BackgroundWorker but using the principal Thread (code below)

```
 View.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
 {
   StockMinWindow MinWindow = new StockMinWindow(StockMinList);
   MinWindow.Owner = View;
   MinWindow.ShowDialog();
 }));
```

Hope it helps.